# What mean circle with letter on scheme?

Tags: schematics

I have connected circles, but I dont know what is this exactly and do I need them on a PCB?

[image]

[image: full scheme]

thanks for feedback.

Comment: Have you read what the accompanying text says?

Comment: I dont have any accompanying text, I have only scheme and need to create pcb for it.

Comment: Where do the circuit nodes connect to?  (That are cut off at the bottom of your fragment of the schematic diagram?  Perhaps it is a current shunt to measure the battery consumption.  Impossible to answer you question without better context. At least seeing the ENTIRE circuit including the OTHER ends of the "A" and "B" connections.

Comment: I will add full scheme to description.

Comment: I think you will find they are two taps on a piece of wire, which acts as a current measuring shunt. The resulting voltage is filtered by R2,C1 and amplified in DA1-1 to provide a measurement of the current drawn from the battery. There is no information about the dimensions fo the shunt, or its resistance, so you will either have to find the relevant documentation or reverse engineer from an actual unit, or guess what you think the resistance (and therefore current measurement gain) should be. The circles may indicate a sliding tap, i.e. adjust on test.

Comment: There isn't a standard for this – only concurrent ones. Some schematics don't even use connecting dots but overleap all non-connecting wires instead. From what I know from old GDR schematics, non-filled dots are connectors. (But the schematics is modern, see the transformer symbol.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection between (A) and (B) is a current shunt. The amplifier DA1 senses the voltage difference between (A) and (B) to measure how much current is coming out (or going in) to the battery GB1.  That shunt could be a special trace on the circuit board. Or it could be a piece of wire as @Brian Drummond suggests.

You cannot successfully copy this circuit without some knowledge of the resistance value of that shunt.  That information is not shown in this schematic diagram.